# Repository pattern where does data context dispose go?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

Watching few examples that use repository pattern like StoreFront I couldn't figure out where is `context.Dispose()` called? Wouldn't not disposing of data context lead to memory leaks? or is it just one Data context for each respoitory for the lifetime of application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a `using` statement, which you should be doing, the call is automatically disposed as it implements the `IDisposable` interface.

Such as:

```
public int GetThingCount()
{
    using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())  // context is created here
    {
        return context.Things.Count();
    } // it is automatically disposed of here even in the event of an exception
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the
>   Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it
>   as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope
>   as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is
>   read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.
>
> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler. The code example
>   earlier expands to the following code at compile time (note the extra
>   curly braces to create the limited scope for the object):

Comment: Yea I know using statement but look at this video [Storefront](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-4-linq-to-sql-spike) they are creating new context somewhere at 14:00 but never calling dispose? I was thinking that there is a reson for them not to use `using` statement?

Comment: In the video they are using tests, not production running code. This code won't start up and stay up all the time, if it did, absolutely yes it would cause leaks. But as you run tests in the IDE, the code starts up runs and then ends.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I guess the best way is to stick with using statements.

Comment: It's really the easiest way to ensure you are disposing your objects, otherwise you would need to implement a try/catch/finally block and explicitly dispose the object. That's just a lot of code noise that the `using` block will do for you automatically.

Comment: Disposing context objects too early has some disadvantages as well check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the context object you mean the `DataContext` object that is created by **Entity Framework** or **Linq2Sql**. The fact is usually you should wrap the classes that implements `IDisposable` by `using` statement or call the `Dispose()` directly but in the case of these data context objects this is not really required.

Here is an excellent [post](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t.aspx) written by Stephen Walther that clearly says that.

> Therefore, you really don’t get any huge benefits from calling
>   Dispose() on the DataContext object. The only slight benefit is that
>   the Dispose() method sets several objects to null so that they can be
>   collected earlier by the garbage collector. Unless you are worried
>   about every byte used by your application, or you are tracking a huge
>   number of objects with your DataContext, I wouldn’t worry too much
>   about the memory overhead of the DataContext object.

Comment: IMO every class that implements IDisposable should be Disposed, no matter what, I am yet to see any advantages of not disposing an object, it is just trade between one line of code for better performance, even if it means saving few bytes. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: I'm not denying that fact, but in the case of context objects things are little different and you should use do that carefully. Plz go through the link shared in my answer completely.

Comment: I don't know if I missed something, are you reffering to the part where he can use IQueryable in the view by not diposing Data Context instead of IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DI it can manage the lifecycle of the item for you. Here's an example in [Ninject](http://ninject.org)

```
kernel.Bind<ProjectAdapter.INIT1_DEVEntities>()
              .ToSelf()
              .InRequestScope()
              .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString",
            ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<string>("efString"))
```